# AH01630: client denied by server configuration Apache

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I get this error when trying to access localhost via a browser.

> 403 Forbidden

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Here is my configuration file:

etc/apache2.conf

```
    # This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
    # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
    # the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
    # hints.
    #
    #
    # Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
    # The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
    # upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian'sA
    # default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
    # virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
    # order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
    # possible.

    # It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
    # below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
    #
    #   /etc/apache2/
    #   |-- apache2.conf
    #   |   `--  ports.conf
    #   |-- mods-enabled
    #   |   |-- *.load
    #   |   `-- *.conf
    #   |-- conf-enabled
    #   |   `-- *.conf
    #   `-- sites-enabled
    #       `-- *.conf
    #
    #
    # * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
    #   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
    #   web server.
    #
    # * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
    #   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
    #   customized anytime.
    #
    # * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
    #   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
    #   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
    #   respectively.
    #
    #   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
    #   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
    #   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
    #   their respective man pages for detailed information.
    #
    # * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
    #   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
    #   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
    #   work with the default configuration.


    # Global configuration
    #

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
    #
    # NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
    # mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
    # at );
    # you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
    #
    # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
    #
    #ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

    #
    # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
    #
    Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

    #
    # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
    # identification number when it starts.
    # This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    #
    PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

    #
    # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
    #
    Timeout 300

    #
    # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
    # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
    #
    KeepAlive On

    #
    # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
    # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
    # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
    #
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

    #
    # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
    # same client on the same connection.
    #
    KeepAliveTimeout 5


    # These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
    Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

    #
    # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
    # e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
    # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
    # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
    # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
    # nameserver.
    #
    HostnameLookups Off

    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a 
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a 
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
    # "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
    #
    LogLevel warn

    # Include module configuration:
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

    # Include list of ports to listen on
    Include ports.conf


    # Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
    # not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
    # The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
    # the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
    # your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
    # access here, or in any related virtual host.
    
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    

    
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    

    
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    

    #
    #   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #   AllowOverride None
    #   Require all granted
    #




    # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
    # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
    # directive.
    #
    AccessFileName .htaccess

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
    # viewed by Web clients.
    #
    
        Require all granted
    


    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive.
    #
    # These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
    # (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
    # requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
    # requests.
    #
    # Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
    # Use mod_remoteip instead.
    #
    LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    # Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
    # see README.Debian for details.

    # Include generic snippets of statements
    IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

    # Include the virtual host configurations:
    IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

apache log

```
>[Wed Jun 17 18:18:38.560856 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 8872] [client 192.168.1.XX:XXXXX] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/prestashop
```

and configuration that I followed on forums went wrong

etc/apache2/sites-enabled/prestashop.conf

```
    
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/prestashop

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    


        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I've added to the apache and I updated the service and always the same mistake I'd like to know why it does not work maybe I'd like chmod this website is accesible locally on any media type Please your help and good evening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things I see just looking at the configuration.

You have your vhost config named

```
etc/apache2/sites-enabled/prestashop.config
```

But that is not the file type that is being included in the apache.conf file.

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Your apache setup looks for `.conf` files **not** `.config` so it's most likely not even reading your vhost file.

Also I would set my vhost to look like this and would include the `Directory` directive.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

      ServerName localhost
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/prestashop

      <Directory /var/www/html/prestashop>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
      </Directory>

      # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
      # error, crit, alert, emerg.
      # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
      # modules, e.g.
      #LogLevel info ssl:warn

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
```

And restart apache when you make all your changes.

Comment: Thanks Panama Jack I trying tomorrow because I have not the machine in question next to me I answer you tomorrow if everything works and thank you again for this reactivity